# wysihtml5 Dissable Parser Rules when pasting but enable for prepoluted text and typing?

Tags: wysihtml5

Using the wysihtml5 editor, is there a way to disable the parser rules for pasting, or simply paste plain text? Such that only plain text, with no tags or any other formatting is pasted? Commenting out my parser rule does not work for me because I still want pre-populated text (with anchor and line-break tags) to be parsed by my parser rules. Although not essential, I also would like the editor to detect URLs and create anchors as I type, but not necessarily when pasting.

The reason I want to do this is because a lot of garbage characters (like new lines %0A and span tags) are pasted when pasting using the parser rules (specially from MSWord, but also from web content). Pasting plain text would prevent random hidden content from being pasted.

Just for reference, my parser rules are extremely simple:

```
var wysihtml5ParserRules = {
  tags: {
    br:     {},
    a:      {
      set_attributes: {
        target: "_blank",
        rel:    "nofollow"
      },
      check_attributes: {
        href:   "url" // important to avoid XSS
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want plain text all the time, go to your project Scripts and you will find file *wysihtml5-toolbar.min.js*

Find text

> wysihtml5.dom.getPastedHtml=function(a){var b;return
>   a.clipboardData&&(wysihtml5.lang.array(a.clipboardData.types).contains("text/html")?b=a.clipboardData.getData("text/html"):wysihtml5.lang...

Change b=a.clipboardData.getData(**"text/html"**) to **"text/plain"**